# Extension host terminated unexpectedly issue with VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can someone please help to get rid of this issue?

[image: https://AlfaLavalIoT@dev.azure.com/AlfaLavalIoT/ALIoT/_git/automated-performance-report]

Comment: You have a broken extension installed. Disable or uninstall one by one until the thing goes away. Then you can update or get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this excellent post by 'aravind ks' for a fix!

[stackoverflow.com/questions/70052961](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70123906/extension-host-terminated-unexpectedly-issue-with-vs-code)

The solution (redacted, edited):

**[Fixed]: Extension host terminated unexpectedly**

Extension Bisect (EB) uses a binary search algorithm to help find the issue root cause extension (or extensions).

Open vs code and launch the command palette with Ctrl + Shift + p; then enter 'Extension Bisect'. You should see a pop-up window like this:

[image: Extension Bisect progress dialog]

Waiting a bit longer than normal for the problem to appear helps.

If an *[ Extension host terminated unexpectedly ]* error dialog is raised, select the '**This is bad**' option. Otherwise, select '**Good now**'.

I don't know if the '**Stop Bisect**' selection triggers a memoize/store - leaving disabled extensions unmarked? in the preexisting auto alpha-sort mix.